# Urequests can't parse response data

Tags: python-requests, micropython

I'm trying to talk to my nanoleaf over my ESP8266 board. I'm using micropython and the urequests library I installed using upip.install('urequests').

`urequests.get` works and I can parse the response from something like: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

However when I try to parse the response from my nanoleaf with `reponse.text` the call just stops. I'm testing it over the UART REPL and it just does nothing until I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then I get a keyboard interrupt. Using normal python on my x86 and requests with the same line works.

I'm using:

```
response = urequests.get(url)
response.text
```

Curl returns this from the nanoleaf:

```
{"on":{"value":true},"brightness":{"value":76,"max":100,"min":0},"hue":{"value":28,"max":360,"min":0},"sat":{"value":66,"max":100,"min":0},"ct":{"value":2700,"max":6500,"min":1200},"colorMode":"effect"}
```

Is that a memory issue? I'm not even trying to get the json, just the text result.

Comment: Have you sent the right parameters to `nanoleaf` `API`? also you can use `requests` module.

Comment: Yes, same request works with curl and the normal python requests module. Which doesn't work on micropython :)